# How to display latest or all posts (pages) of a parent page, in a single page in TYPO3 CMS

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a **TYPO3** TypoScript **html template** and want to show in a single page (called: "competitions"), a list of all competitions with their image and title and this should be links for each of them ('competition'). I have thought to make a page ('competitions') and subpages ('single cmpetition'). I'm not using Fluid actually. How can i get and display those in main page? Or is another way to achieve this ?

Comment: i would appreciate if you could provide more details of TYPO3 version and template methods,
for your answer you can do this by page content RECORD, and where you have to include that page static by page id and those all content will be laid on "competitions" page.

Comment: Im using Typo3 7.6 and the 'traditional' TypoScript Templating method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on your data structure (is the relevant info you want to show stored in the pages record or do you want access tt_content records inside that pages) it is more or less easy.

you always can access the informations with typoscript, but those constructs may get complicated. that means: developing the TS may take some time and the following rendering might also get complex and might take some time.

the easiest way: all information in pages records:

```
temp.competitions = CONTENT
temp.competitions {
    table = pages
    select {
        pidInList = this
        orderBy = sorting
    }

   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
        wrap = <div class="teaser">|</div>

        10 = TEXT
        10.field = title
        10.wrap = <h3>|</h3>

        20 = TEXT
        20.field = abstract
        20.wrap = <div class="abstract">|</div>

        30 = IMAGE
        :

    }
}
```

Comment: But images (IMAGE) are not in the pages table, right? can i get them from tt_content?

Comment: you can store images in the pages record. that's the easy way. otherwise you can extract the images from the tt_content records in the page. That can be done with cascaded CONTENT objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer